# Can someone help me understand what this regex is doing?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

Can someone break down what this Regex is matching please?

```vb
Regex.Match("<a>", "^<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)( [^>]*)?>$")
```

Comment: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/olzUVg/1) is a good tool for understanding what specific regular expressions are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, explained and *formatted*

```
 ^                             # The beginning of the string BOS
 <                             # A literal '<'
 (                             # (1 start), Capture group 1
      [a-zA-Z]                      # Start with a letter
      [a-zA-Z0-9]*                  # 0 or more letter or number
 )                             # (1 end)
 (                             # (2 start) Optional Capture group 2
      [^>]*                         # 0 or more, non '>' character
 )?                            # (2 end)
 >                             # A literal '>'
 $                             # The end of the string EOS
```

A word of advice, this construct has its place `([^>]*)?`
but it should be written as this `([^>]*?)`.

Comment: There is a space before `[^>]*`, so `( [^>]*)?` cannot be replaced with `([^>]*?)`.

Comment: @Toto - Missed that space, but `[^>]` matches a space. But I don't think he actually requires a space before it could match, since it's optional. But, maybe.. but I doubt it. It's probably a typo !!

Comment: The space is mandatory when there is another character after, They want a space and some (0 or more) non `>` or nothing at all. OP matches `<tag attr="blah">` but yours matches `<tagattr="blah">`

Comment: @Toto - Anything to remove the possible _null_ `^<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?=[ ]|>)([^>]*?)>$` matches `<tag attr="blah">` or `<tag >`, or `<tag>`  but not  `<tagattr="blah">`

Comment: @Toto - And, if it were about html parsing I would have suggested using this `<[\w:]+(?=\s|/?>)((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+)>`